# How to assign weight to selection list options? and do calculations with the weights? in jira software

Tags: jira, gil

I have a field called 'urgency' of single select list type, and it has the options: 'high', 'medium', 'low'. I would like you to want weights 9, 6 and 3 respectively. And multiply these weights by values from other fields to have an indicator that represents priority.

I tried looking for a custom field type that allows manipulation through Scripts. Called Scripted Field, but apparently that field has been discontinued.